# warning: `action=false` and `href` should not be used together

Tags: reactjs

This morning, I wasn't doing anything fancy. here is my React JS component.

```
const ListSimple = () => (
    <div className="ListSimple">
        <h3>Simple List</h3>
        <ListGroup>
        <ListGroupItem href="#">Cras justo odio</ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem href="#">Dapibus ac facilisis in</ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem href="#">Morbi leo risus</ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem href="#">Porta ac consectetur ac</ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem href="#">Vestibulum at eros</ListGroupItem>
        </ListGroup>
    </div>
    );
    export default ListSimple;
```

the code runs just fine, but, now for each list item, I getting the above error in the console. Firefox.

```
Warning: `action=false` and `href` should not be used together. warning.js:34
    printWarning warning.js:34
    warning warning.js:57
    ListGroupItem ListGroupItem.js:41
    React 13
    push history.ts:643
    navigate hooks.tsx:212
    useLinkClickHandler index.tsx:819
    handleClick index.tsx:458
    React 23
    js index.js:8
    factory react refresh:6
```

how can i get rid of this warning?

Comment: Does it only error when running in Firefox or even other browsers?

Comment: I get it on Firefox. and after you asked, checked on Edge. same error on both.